# How can I pack only part of the packages in my projects to a .jar file with maven

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have developed a java project with some code in a package *com.examples.utils* which I would like share with other projects. Can I pack only this package(not the whole project) to a jar file with maven?

I am now using eclipse. With it I can export the packages I want to a jar file and add it the build path of targeting project manually. It works but I have to do it manually every time there is any update from the *com.examples.utils*. Besides, there is no version control over the jar file I exported.

So I am thinking about using maven to do it. Do I have to create a new project with only *com.examples.utils* included. Or can I pack only this package(not the whole project) to a jar file with maven?

Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create separate project which create a jar and it will be a (light) common dependency

If you just want to exclude certain packages when used as dependency you can add

```
   <dependency>
        <!--  ..  ->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>your.package</groupId>
                <artifactId>your.artifact.id</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a maven artifact  and group if and push to repository. Users who is in need of your functionality they can add your dependency in thier pom. If thier is any update u can add in the same jar or create a new version .